# How to bypass Twitter omniauth "email can't be blank" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, twitter, omniauth

I am having a little trouble with Twitter authentication. I keep getting the email can't be blank, and redirect to sign up, but after inserting email and clicking sign up, I still get the same error. I tried making it unneeded, but I get the error saying that someone with "" email exists already. 
Thanks.

Devise Routes.rb

```
    def has_role?(role)
        return true;
      end 
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.username = auth.info.nickname
      end
    end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  if session["devise.user_attributes"]
    new(session["devise.user_attributes"]) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
    end
  else
    super
  end
end

def password_required?
  super && provider.blank?
end

def update_with_password(params, *options)
  if encrypted_password.blank?
    update_attributes(params, *options)
  else
    super
  end
end
end

              Call Back Controller 
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

Comment: Try to clear cache and active logins and then retry

Comment: Can we see some code from where you are getting this error from?

Comment: do you have a unique constraint on email?

Comment: is `attr_accessible :email` set on your `User` model?

Comment: No. I am using Rails 4.

Comment: I added some code. Sorry for not doing it earlier..

Answer (score 2):

You can define username to be your "authentication key" instead of email by
uncommenting this line

config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

in config/initializers/devise.rb

and changing it to

config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]

Answer (score 1):

i also had the same problem.
this error arises due the fact that in devise User model Email field is set to NotNull.
Solutions:-

> 1.Set email field in devise to allow null values.
>
> 2.so i had saved the email from twitter in my devise email field this is the code for twitter

```
def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)

  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user
    temp = Tempfile.new([auth["uid"], ".jpg"])
    temp.binmode
    temp.write(open(auth["info"]["image"]).read)
    user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                         provider:auth.provider,
                         uid:auth.uid,
                         email:auth.info.email,
                         password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                         image:temp                          
                         )
        user.build_profile(name:user.name,image:temp)
    user.profile.save     
  end
  user
end
```